# Need regex to parse the where clause query in java

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I need your expertise in a regex to solve one of my problems.

The where clause for a query will come as output from a REST service request payload. I want to first validate and parse using the Java Parser.

I tried up to some extent. I am very new to REGEX. I wrote some code to validate that.
But it's working partially. Can someone please suggest the correct REGEX and if possible please explain how it works. This is very helpful.

I am pasting my code snippet.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DummyTester {
    public DummyTester() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "productName co Jam and (expiryDate gt 2020-02-06T00:00:00.000Z or Quantity gt 500)";

        checkRegex(text);
        checkRegex("userName eq bjensen");
        checkRegex("familyName co O'Malley");
        checkRegex("userName eq bjensen and familyName co O'Malley");
        checkRegex("userName eq bjensen or familyName co O'Malley");
        checkRegex("(userName eq bjensen and familyName co O'Malley) OR (userName eq bjensen or familyName co O'Malley");
        //So many such combinations may exist.

        //System.out.println(text);
    }

    static String checkRegex(String tester) {

        String regex ="(\\w[\\w\\d]* \\s*(?:co|eq|gt)\\s* \\w[\\w\\d\\-\\:]*)* ?(?:and|or|AND|OR)?";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(tester);
        boolean b = m.matches(); 
        System.out.println("matcher is   : "+ b);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to parse any potential where clause, including sub-queries? A regex approach could become very complicated very quickly. You might be better off looking at a Parser such as Javacc or ANTLR or one of the many others... Also, to help people that may want to help you craft a regex, can you provide the output when you run the above - along with a brief summary of what you were hoping would happen (and if unclear, what was actually wrong with the output you got)?

Comment: Also, rethink your REST design. This has printed "SQL injection" all over it (no matter how clever you are about parsing it)

Comment: FYI, you can use https://regex101.com/ to try your regex variations quickly before writing it in code.

Comment: JavaCC and ANTLR are again open source API which need to be installed, which is not permitted for me. So I want to check is there by other way we can achieve this.